# Скачивание файла (не zip, gzip и т.д., а обычного)

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, подскажите функцию на PHP, с помощью которой можно сделать автоматическое скачивание.
Например, пользователь заходит на страницу `/site.php` и ему автоматически предлагается **скачать** файл `/content/kartinka.png` или же `/content/readme.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:
html страница после загрузки направляет браузер на другую страницу средствами js:
`location.href="content.php";`
в свою очередь content.php выдает файл html, но с mime-типом бинарного файла.
`header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
    echo(file_get_content("file.html"));  
die();`